how can I install the "plyr" package in R version 4.4?
After updating R to version 4.4, most of the packages are gone and I need to reinstall them. Now, I'm having trouble downloading the "plyr" package, even though the github pages say that the current status of the "plyr" package is retired, I need to install "plyr" before I can install the phyoseq package. However, when I try I get the following error. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?
> install.packages("plyr")
Installing package into ‘/home/sskoldas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/plyr_1.8.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 401488 bytes (392 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 392 KB

* installing *source* package ‘plyr’ ...
** package ‘plyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0’
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0’
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'     -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-H8urij/r-base-4.4.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/routines.h:26,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:128,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h: In member function ‘std::streamsize Rcpp::Rstreambuf<OUTPUT>::xsputn(const char*, std::streamsize) [with bool OUTPUT = true; std::streamsize = long int]’:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:53:20: warning: field precision specifier ‘.*’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::streamsize’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
   53 |         Rprintf("%.*s", num, s);
      |                  ~~^~   ~~~
      |                    |    |
      |                    int  std::streamsize {aka long int}
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h: In member function ‘std::streamsize Rcpp::Rstreambuf<OUTPUT>::xsputn(const char*, std::streamsize) [with bool OUTPUT = false; std::streamsize = long int]’:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:57:21: warning: field precision specifier ‘.*’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::streamsize’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
   57 |         REprintf("%.*s", num, s);
      |                   ~~^~   ~~~
      |                     |    |
      |                     int  std::streamsize {aka long int}
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:181,
                 from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from RcppExports.cpp:4:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/print.h: In function ‘void Rcpp::warningcall(SEXP, const string&)’:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/print.h:30:19: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
   30 |     Rf_warningcall(call, s.c_str());
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:204: RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘plyr’
* removing ‘/home/sskoldas/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4/plyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpWy0Zao/downloaded_packages’


Open a terminal, what does gcc --version give you?

Which OS and version are you on?

As plyr is 'retired', it is suggested to move on to dplyr for data.frame(s) or purrr for lists. In the above, I think it is Werror=format-security that is causing the 'problem' as g++ -std=gnu++17 is stricter than 11, but just a guess.

@jay.sf it says:
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0 Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Weird, have exactly same platform and compiler and successfully plyr 1.8.9 installed.

What is in your ~/.R/Makevars file and also /etc/R/Makeconf?

Mybe try install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plyr/plyr_1.8.8.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL)  or even earlier versions, phylosec depends on plyr (>= 1.8.3)/

@G.Grothendieck Also thought maybe editing compiler flags, however I've recently gone through similar update process without need to change anything. Definitely worth a look.

Since you are on a Debian derivative you may benefit from https://github.com/eddelbuettel/r2u

@jay.sf I tried this: install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/plyr/plyr_1.8.9.tar.gz", type="source", repos=NULL) and It worked. Thank you so much!!

You're welcome. Maybe check your/etc/apt/sources.list if they correspond to the recommended settings on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/. This should affect getOption("repos") which is used as the default repos= parameter (i.e. if you leave it empty) in install.packages().
